# Vim doesn't display rightly with color-scheme

Tags: vim

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and my vim74 is got from apt-get. Some weird thing happened when I try to get some plugin and a colorscheme for my vim.
Here is link a showing what it looks like:
https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/13230384/12009507/31cee8e6-acb5-11e5-8183-7b4fc88d5b24.png

This is my .vimrc:

```
set background=dark
colorscheme solarized
"colorscheme molokai    
"colorscheme phd
```

Could you tell what causes this? Is the old vim colorscheme .vim file in the global path(/usr/share) related to this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "weird thing"?

Comment: Also is your terminal set to 256 color mode?

Comment: Thanks so much. It was that problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure that your terminal is set to 256 color mode. This depends on your setup but in most cases, this will probably work for you:

Place this in your `.bashrc` file:

```
export TERM=xterm-256color
```

If you are using iTerm2 you might need to set this option in the application settings,
`preferences -> profiles -> report terminal type`

Comment: iTerm is totally off-topic here

Comment: @romainl - I needed to make those changes in iterm's preferences for 256 color mode to work for me. Why do you feel that it's off topic?

Comment: Because the OP doesn't use iTerm or even Mac OS X.

Comment: If I was only answering for this one specific user then you might be correct. I faced exactly the same issue on a non linux machine. This one solution doesn't (and shouldn't) be limited to help only the person who asked it. SEO won't ignore this post when someone else searches for "color-scheme messed up". The answer contains 100% of the required information and also some extra info that might assist other future visitors. My answer is mostly according to the supplied tags...

Comment: Same or similar questions have been asked and answered hundreds of times [here and elsewhere](https://www.google.com/search?q=vim+color-scheme+messed+up) so… good luck on your way to page 156 ;-).

Comment: @romainl - thanks for your feedback - unfortunately, I don't feel like this conversation is contributing at all to the post at hand. If you feel the need to make some improvements to my post you are more than welcome.